# MFMailComposeViewController - UI issue in groups list while adding recipients

Tags: ios7

In `MFMailComposeViewController` when I touch the `addRecipients` button, the contacts list opens and when I select the groups button, 
the groups gets listed with transparent background. This looks clumsy as the groups table overlapping with the contacts list. 
I face this issue in iOS7. This happens with some projects which are created in `xcode 4.2`.

Comment: What is it you're trying to do?

Comment: We are presenting the mfmailcomposer mail client in our app.. But in the add contacts - > groups list is transparent unlike the contacts -> groups list in default apple photos app. This happens only in ios7

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an issue with iOS7, i just looked around their default 'app store' app and was able to find the same issue in it.